# best practice to abort action method

Tags: ajax, jsf, action, abort

what is the best apporach to abort a running action method in JSF?

e.g. I have an action, which performs some complicated DB operations and then returns the result site (e.g. "complete.xhtml").

How can I abort the running action-method (and do e.g. rollbacks?). maybe with ajax?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html#bncip

Comment: What about `return null` in action method?

Comment: return null wont solve the problem, because I want it to finish normally if I don't click a kind of "abort"-button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the usual approach is to use `actionListener` and `action` together.

When button is clicked the `actionListener` will get called first.

Check for your condition/validation at `actionListener` and if it doesn't match, then `throw` 
`javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException` then your `action` method will not get called.

[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/event/AbortProcessingException.html)

Comment: so in JSF there is no true opportinity to "abort" a running action method (which uploads a file and takes some time?)?